# dplyr group_by() %>% summarize_all() throws error "Error: cannot modify grouping variable" with back-ticked variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

I was having an issue with a `group_by() %>% summarize_all()` operation, where it was throwing an error

> "Error: cannot modify grouping variable"

even though `summarize_all()` is not supposed to attempt to modify the grouping variable that had spaces and was back-ticked. I tried many many things, and it finally behaved when I changed the variable name to not contain a space.

Is this normal behavior? I've gotten to liking using back-ticked variables since it makes the names more human-readable.

Here's a self-contained example:

```
x <- sample(c("Dog", "Banana", "Happy"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
y <- runif(2000, min = 0, max = 20)

df <- data.frame(`Grouping Variable` = x,
     value = y)

df2 <- as.tbl(df)

df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(Grouping.Variable) %>% summarize_all(sum)
df3

# all good! 

df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(`Grouping.Variable`) %>% summarize_all(sum)
df3

# all good!

df2.2 <- df2 %>% rename(`Grouping Variable` = Grouping.Variable)
df3.2 <- df2.2 %>% group_by(`Grouping Variable`) %>% summarize_all(sum)

# Noooo!!!
```

Comment: In general, it's a good idea, and good coding etiquette, to avoid variable names (and file names) with spaces. In R, when you have variable names with spaces, you have to use the back tick, which is easy to avoid. Underscore and camel-case are typical styles to indicate spaces in many programming styles, while R allows for dot spacing. Some people (like hadley) don't like dot spacing because it is sometimes used in an object-oriented syntax to refer to object classes and methods/attributes.

Comment: I recommend not overcomplicating your life.

Comment: Although, I agree that one should avoid spaces in names, you could rename to 'Grouping Variable' after summarizing as in `df2 %>% group_by('Grouping.Variable') %>% summarize_all(sum) %>% rename('Grouping Variable' = Grouping.Variable)`.  I replaced backticks in the code with single quotes just for display but backticks should be used in the code as before.

Comment: I agree with the previous commenters. If I want spaces in my variable names, for example, when I output a table to a document or spreadsheet, then I do all the name-changing at the end, right before I output the table. However, if you absolutely have to have spaces in your variable names for some reason, you could do something like this: `summarize_at(vars(-matches("Grouping")), sum)`.